# Python - Text to speech - British / American accents

Tags: python, text-to-speech, speech

I am looking for some resources allowing me to convert text to speech toggling from American to British pronunciation.

In other words, after entering a sentence (text) get the speech either with British or American accent.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This question is out of scope for SO, as it is a question asking for a recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

gtts (Google text-to-speech), which is a Python library to easily interact with a Google API for speech synthesis, offers a long list of languages, including different variants of English. A list of the supported languages, together with code snippets to get started, can be found here: https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/convert-text-to-speech-in-python#Online_Text_to_speech